# Cypress unable to find element and submit

Tags: cypress

I am using cypress to login a page but I am hitting error at submit.
there is 2 Login buttons at the same page. how do I locate the right login button?
for quick qorkaround I added this syntax behind last command. but i wondering how can I locate the button if same page consist of same name and type of Login button.

```
.type('{enter}')
```

without workaround, error

```
cy.submit() can only be called on a single form. Your subject contained 2 form elements.
```

the web page element:

```
<form action="/test/abc" method="get"><h6>Login with your own user</h6><input maxlength="9" name="ID" placeholder="testID" style="margin-right: 5px" value="ABC123"><input maxlength="255" name="ID_FullName" placeholder="Name" style="margin-right: 5px" value="Tester"><input name="EntID" placeholder="UPASS" style="margin-right: 5px" value="B12345"><select name="Role" style="margin-right: 5px"><option value="Acceptor">Acceptor</option><option value="Admin">Admin</option><option value="User">User</option></select><button autofocus="" type="submit">Login</button></form>
```

another element at the same page, form too.

```
<form action="/test/abc" method="get"><select name="Srt" style="width: 100%; display: block; font-size: 25px"><option value="111233">fdsfdf - teset</option><option value="fdsfsd">rewr - 201005853W</option></select><button autofocus="" style="margin-top: 10px;  width:100%; display: block; height:80px; font-size: 20px" type="submit">Login</button></form>
```

my scripts:

```
   cy.get('form').within(($form) => {
    cy.get('input[name="ID"]').type('A12345678')
    cy.get('input[name="ID_FullName"]').type('Accp John')
    cy.get('input[name="EntID"]').type('B56789')
    cy.get('[name="Role"]').select('Acceptor')
    cy.root().submit()
  })
```

Comment: have your tried to `cy.get('[name="Role"]')`? ofc, this will locate the element, however the logic of clicking desired option is to be chained further

Comment: @AlexIzbas it works now. thanks for suggestion but the cy.root().submit() returned error cy.submit() can only be called on a single form. Your subject contained 2 form elements.

Comment: curious, as `cy.root()` submits the form yielded from 'within' and based on the snipped  you attached there is only one submit element. In this case will suggest just to `cy.get('button[type=submit]').click()` ;)

Comment: @AlexIzbas i tried your suggestion , error cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element. I edited main post, added the element of another similar form displayed at same page.

Comment: cannot understand your second element. Could you provide the HTML  for it as well, please?

Comment: `cy.get('form')` is too generic, can you try by updating the 'selector query' with a `unique parent element`?

Comment: @Sree.Bh i am using Inspect element and copy element. any better way for me to extract the relevant info for you?

Comment: @user12158726: As you mentioned '2 login buttons'...when you inspect element, can you copy the html from the element which includes both the 'login buttons'. For example refer: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srbh_ya16/893uohdv/) : it has two forms but the parent div are not having the same class so second form can be uniquely selected using `cy.get('.form2 form')`

Comment: @Sree.Bh sorry the main post has coded wrong details. i modified, please see, there are 2 elements of 2 forms. but nothing unique for me to grab.

Comment: So you need to distinguish using `.eq`: `cy.get('form').eq(<0 or 1>).within(...)`

Comment: Second approach: for first form: `cy.contains('Login with your own user').parent('form').within(...)` and for second form: `get('select[name="Srt"]').parent('form').within(...)`